# MVVM ListView SelectedItem Properties

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I want to do some checks with a list. I was able to add my data to the list. But I don't know how to use these added tools.

How can I find out which elements in the comboBoxes in this list from my selected code.

or Checkboxes are selected and not selected? how can I learn.

Or if I want to change title and want Device-20 instead of Device-1, how can I do?

My Xaml Code

```
<ListView Name="SensorList" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="SensorList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Image">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" MaxHeight="25" MaxWidth="25" Source="{Binding ImageData}"></Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Explanation}" Header="Description" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Options">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Width="100">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test" />
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test2" />
                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test3" />
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Status}"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

C# ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<DeviceList> deviceList;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<DeviceList> DeviceList
    {
        get
        {
            if (deviceList == null)
            {
                deviceList = new ObservableCollection<DeviceList>();
            }

            return deviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (deviceList != value)
            {
                deviceList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private DeviceList selectedDeviceList;
    public DeviceList SelectedDeviceList
    {
        get
        {
            return SelectedDeviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedDeviceList != value)
            {
                SelectedDeviceList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# DeviceListClass

```
public class DeviceList
{
    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return this._Title; }
        set { this._Title = value; }
    }

    private string _Explanation;
    public string Explanation
    {
        get { return this._Explanation; }
        set { this._Explanation = value; }
    }

    private int _DeviceId;
    public int DeviceId
    {
        get { return this._DeviceId; }
        set { this._DeviceId = value; }
    }

    private bool _Status;
    public bool Status
    {
        get { return this._Status; }
        set { this._Status = value; }
    }

    private BitmapImage _ImageData;
    public BitmapImage ImageData
    {
        get { return this._ImageData; }
        set { this._ImageData = value; }
    }

}
```

MainWindow InitializeCode

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

List Image

[image]

Comment: You are close, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your properties then hook to some *Changed* event from your UI to act after user changed data, then just work against your data.

Comment: Also, you might want to change your question title because it's very unclear.

Comment: The INotifyPropertyChanged implementation looks very complex. If you have a title suggestion, you can make corrections. Thank you so much.

Comment: Since you tagged "MVVM" you should use bindings instead of events in code-behind, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ObservableCollection named `DeviceList` and a property `SelectedDeviceList` to your ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<DeviceList> deviceList;
public ObservableCollection<DeviceList> DeviceList
{
    get
    {
        if(deviceList == null)
        {
            deviceList = new ObservableCollection<DeviceList>();
        }

        return deviceList;
    }
    set
    {
        if(deviceList != value)
        {
            deviceList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private DeviceList selectedDeviceList;
public DeviceList SelectedDeviceList
{
    get
    {
        return selectedDeviceList;
    }
    set
    {
        if(SelectedDeviceList != value)
        {
            selectedDeviceList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the items to the `DeviceList` in the constructor of the ViewModel or somewhere else, depending on your architecture

```
DeviceList.Add(new DeviceList{Title="Device-1",Explanation ="Explanation-1", ImageData=LoadImage("sensor1.png"),DeviceId = 1,Status = true});
DeviceList.Add(new DeviceList{Title="Device-2",Explanation ="Explanation-2", ImageData=LoadImage("sensor2.png"),DeviceId =2,Status = false});
...
```

Add `SelectedItem` to your XAML ListView:

```
<ListView Name="SensorList" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeviceList}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="SensorList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

and make sure that you set the ViewModels DataContext to the View and that you've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

To iterate over all items to see which checkbox is checked you simply do

```
foreach(var device in DeviceList) 
{
    // Checkbox checked?
    if(device.Status == true) 
        ...

    // Change title
    // Set those bindings to Mode=TwoWay in your View: {Binding Title,Mode=TwoWay}
    device.Title = "Device-20";
}
```

Comment: I made the additions to the viewModel as described. The problem I am having is I cannot add DeviceList.Add (new Device List {.....}). I did not understand where to add it in ViewModel.
Also thank you for explaining the logic of work in a good way.

Comment: Since you've implemented MVVM you set your View's DataContext to the ViewModel instance (something like `DataContext = MyViewModel`), right ? You can add the initialization of your DeviceList to the constructor of your ViewModel for example. So to the same class where your DeviceList list is implemented.

Comment: I fixed the code above as I am applying now. "public DeviceList SelectedDeviceList" 'I get a System.StackOverflowException error. I am wrong somewhere for sure. Sorry for tiring you out.
DeviceList. Add does not appear when I type.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry. The return value was the property itself (`SelectedDeviceList` instead of `selectedDeviceList`) and not the field. Recopy the code above.

Comment: I cannot use the DeviceList.Add command. What is the reason. DeviceList.Add does not appear in any Button.Click event.

Comment: Ah okay, so you don't have a separate ViewModel? If all your code is in the code-behind of your View then the observable collection named `DeviceList` must be a property in your code-behind. Put all the code from above to the same class (code-behind) were your button.click event is. Also maybe rename the observable collection to `MyDeviceList` so that you don't get confused between class `DeviceList` and property `DeviceList`. I also guess that your class `DeviceList` should be renamed to `Device` to be more accurate whats its actually for.